# How do i add foreign keys to two Innob tables so that they autoupdate each other?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, innodb

I have two tables users and lead_contacts which have similar data. When somebody buys a product they become a user. How should I modify the two create staements below so:

- that the leads table receives a new
  entry with first_name, last_name, company and email, when a user is created.
- the  first_name, last_name, company and email in users table is updated
  automatically when the leads table info is changed

  CREATE TABLE `lead_contacts` (
    `contact_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `company` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `address` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `address_2` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `state` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `country` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `postal_code` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `fax` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `ship_bill_same` enum('Y',  'N') NOT NULL default 'Y',
  `notes` text NOT NULL,
  `admin_notes` text NOT NULL,
  `list_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `lead_list` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `is_master_list` enum('N',  'Y') NOT NULL default 'N',
  `active_work` enum('Y',  'N') NOT NULL default 'Y',
  `parentID` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`contact_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `lead_list` (`lead_list`),
  KEY `is_master_list` (`is_master_list`),
  KEY `active_work` (`active_work`),
  KEY `parentID` (`parentID`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 PACK_KEYS=1;

  CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `userID` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `access_level` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  `company` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username` (`username`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how foreign keys work.

A reference from leads to users means that a row must already exist in users before a row in leads can reference it.

There's no way in SQL to make a dependent table automatically create a row in its parent table on demand.

You could do this with a trigger, I suppose.  But not a foreign key constraints.  Besides, the values to fill into the parent table must come from somewhere.  Either you need to specify them in an INSERT statement in your application or in a trigger, or else use the defaults defined for each column in the users table.  Given that you have a unique constraint on `users.username`, I don't think this would be possible from a trigger.

---

Re: your followup question in the comment:

No, a foreign key can't do what you're describing.  When you modify info in the `leads` table (the table with the foreign key), the **only** thing a foreign key can do is prevent the modification if you try to change the `leads.user_id` column to a value that is not found in the `users` table.

*The foreign key in the child (`leads`) table can't change anything in the parent (`users`) table.*

I'm not sure what is the source of your mistaken understanding.  Did you read it somewhere or see someone do something like this?

Comment: thank you for your prompt answer foreign keys would do this though right?

the first_name, last_name, company and email in users table is updated automatically when the leads table info is changed